# SQLAlchemy model is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have written a login API, It will take email and password arguments, but I am getting this error :

```
 'UserCred' object is not subscriptable
```

this is my code:

```
# This method will Checks and returns the user details in EcoUserCredentials table.
def loginM(email, password):
    try:
        user = EcoUserCredentials.query.filter_by(email=str(email)).first()
        print(user)
        print(type(user))
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            access_token = create_access_token(identity={user['email']})
            print(access_token)
            return jsonify({"token": access_token})
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Invalid username and password"})

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

when I print(user)

output is:

```
<UserCredentials 1001>
```

when I print(type(user))

output is:

```
<class 'Eco_App_APIs.Registration.Model.EcoUserCredentials'>
```

how can I solve this.